# Hide download file location. - Redirect download

Tags: php, redirect, download

I am selling a digital product and want to hide the true location of the download.

So I'm using a redirect script like this:

```
protected function redirectDownload ($realfilename) { 
    ob_start(); 
    $mm_type="application/octet-stream"; 

    header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate"); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type); 
    header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($realfilename)) ); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->fakefilename.'"'); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n"); 

    ob_end_clean(); 
    readfile($realfilename); 
}
```

The zip file is always corrupted when I download it, but when I download it directly it is fine.

Does anyone know why this might be?

I think this was working fine on another server, but would need to confirm that.

If I can't solve this, is there any other techniques or services I can use to do this?

Comment: What's the point of ob_start() and ob_end_clean() here?  There doesn't seem to be any output happening in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the downloaded(corrupted) file in an text-editor, i guess there has already been some output before you call the function.
You should better use ob_start() at the begin of your script instead of the begin of the function.