# Browsers status bar href

Tags: jquery, browser, status

We have a site that has lightbox images but the client does not want to reveal the img src thats displayed in the browser status bar…

Any bright idea how we can achieve this consistently for all browsers?

I would add that this is for a site where we have a thumbnail that links (a href="") to another larger image and its this link thats displayed in the status bar thats the clients main concern.

We have also tried using an option wit the CMS we are using that allows us to use an Obfuscated time limited url to the images, this seemed great but is severely slowed the load times to a point where its unacceptable.

Comment: Which browser shows image `src` in the status bar?? And what lightbox code are you using?

Comment: Load it via ajax. But the URL will always be accessible with only minor effort.

Answer (score 1):

Is the web page itself behind any sort of authentication?

If so, then the correct approach is to take the images out of the public root and run access via an authenticating script. I think Devot:ee has several such tools for ExpressionEngine. Alternatively a simple plugin could take the private path, check for a logged in member and then serve the image.

If there is no authentication on the page then harsh truth is you are all wasting time and I feel your pain! If that's the case I would not abandon the "educating the client" route as if the images are genuinely sensitive then they need proper protection.

As an aside, you may also want to consider [discouraging hotlinking](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=images+prevent+hot+linking&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&aq=f&oq=images+prevent+hot+linking&aqs=chrome.0.57.5722&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a modal dialog. Not exactly a pop up, but it will open another container. Like an overlay. You see people doing this a lot with images, but you can also use this for html. There are a ton of plugins for jquery.

Heres one with some examples though: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

I personally like http://fancybox.net/

Only problem is you can't use ajax to call another website, but you can create a page in php or whatever and get the contents of another page and then return that in ajax.

you would want to use something like curl for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an image in a browser, the browser has to know where that image is located.  Hence the URL of that image can always be seen by the user.  There is no way to hide it from the user.

While you might be able to hide it from the status bar, what stops the user from right clicking the image and say "Open Image in New Tab" (or equivalent). If you were to "disable right clicks" (which is impossible for all intents and purposes), you can easily see the image URL through dev tools like Firebug, etc.

So, while you might disguise the URL a little, there is nothing to stop someone who really wants to find it.

Comment: Yes I agree Steve, if you really want the image you wil find it. I would add that this is for a site where we have a thumbnail that links (a href="") to another larger image and its this link thats displayed in the status bar thats the clients main concern.

Comment: Believe me, I hear you.  i have dealt with clients that have no idea how the web works and were super paranoid about exposing their 'assets'. It's important to educate them, but in the end you have to find a way to make them happy, no matter how stupid it looks to you. :)

Comment: in this case some of the data is sensitive... it may be that we simply rename all the files! (there are thousands though). Thanks again Steve :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the goal is here... but to answer your question just write the image as a base64 encoded string. Examples abound: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples. So it is possible to obscure where the image is located, and in fact it doesn't even have to be outwardly accessible as long as you write the data string on the server.

Comment: Thanks Sam, we are looking at a few add-ons that will help us achieve this.

Comment: No need for an add-on. Any server side language will allow you to easily implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a script that has the location of the image in a data attribute, and bind an event on click that fires the lightbox manually, and uses the location from that data attribute.

Comment: Thanks Alex, thats what I am starting to think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution might be to encode the image path in the page (use base64 for example) and then have an in-between standalone PHP script which receives the encoded file path and returns the original image as a string on the fly.

Obviosuly there's a greater overhead than if you were just serving the image directly but it would prevent the user from ever knowing the real file location or name.

Something like this:

[Hide download file location. - Redirect download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647165/hide-download-file-location-redirect-download)

Might be a good starting point.

:)

Comment: Actually this could also be relevant knowing that this is an ExpressionEngine project - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246246/serving-images-to-get-a-request